# TensorFlow: Integer tensor to file pattern string

Tags: python, string, tensorflow, type-conversion, tensorflow-datasets

In dataset pipeline (`.map()`) I'm using conversion from int tensor to file pattern string for `make_csv_dataset(...)`.

### I get an error:

```
ValueError: No files match `file_pattern` dataset/PAMAP2_Dataset/train/*_Tensor("strided_slice:0", shape=(), dtype=int32).csv.
```

Here is the error: `Tensor("strided_slice:0", shape=(), dtype=int32)` - this should be an integer number not this text .....

### Code

```
labels = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 24 ]
def _make_dataset(idx):
    # shuffle
    activityID = tf.random.shuffle(labels)

    dataset = (
        tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(
           file_pattern=("dataset/PAMAP2_Dataset/train/*_" + str(activityID[idx]) + ".csv"),
           batch_size=1,
           num_epochs=1,
           shuffle=False,
        ).batch(64, drop_remainder=True).shuffle(64)
        
dataset = (
    tf.data.Dataset.range(1)
    .interleave(
        map_func=_make_dataset,
        cycle_length=tf.data.AUTOTUNE,
        num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE,
        deterministic=False,
    )
)
```

Comment: What are you trying to solve actually?

Comment: Read many csv in tf.data.dataset.range() with specified pattern "dataset/PAMAP2_Dataset/train/*_" + str(activityID[idx]) + ".csv". After make_csv_dataset is some preprocessing. Example result is: dataset/PAMAP2_Dataset/train/a_1.csv, dataset/PAMAP2_Dataset/train/b_1.csv, dataset/PAMAP2_Dataset/train/c_1.csv | dataset/PAMAP2_Dataset/train/a_2.csv, dataset/PAMAP2_Dataset/train/b_2.csv, dataset/PAMAP2_Dataset/train/c_2.csv

Comment: Because csv files cannot be mixed like "/*.csv" but by it's activityID and it's done by tf.data.dataset.range() .... See above example of output ... It is mixing csv file only in one activityID group.

Comment: Dataset 1 contains examples only from a_1, b_1, c_1, .... Dataset 2 contains examples only from a_2, b_2, c_2, .... Dataset 3 contains examples only from a_3, b_3, c_3, ....  (this is the result of `tf.data.Dataset.range(1).interleave()`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [bug](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/50260) related to using `tf.data.Dataset.interleave` and `make_csv_dataset`. The recommendation is to use the `CsvDataset` API right now. Try something like this with `tf.io.matching_files` to solve file patterns:

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf

labels = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 24 ]

data = {
  "id": [420, 380, 390],
  "duration": [50, 40, 45]
}

# Create dummy data
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

for i in labels:
  df.to_csv('test_{}.csv'.format(i), index=False)
  
def get_random_path(x, idx):
  return "/content/*_" + str(x[idx].numpy()) + ".csv"

def _make_dataset(idx):
    # shuffle
    activityID = tf.random.shuffle(labels)
    path = tf.py_function(get_random_path, [activityID, idx], Tout=[tf.string])

    dataset = tf.data.experimental.CsvDataset(
           filenames=tf.io.matching_files(path), record_defaults=[tf.int32, tf.int32], header=True)
    return dataset

dataset = (
    tf.data.Dataset.range(1)
    .interleave(_make_dataset,
        cycle_length=tf.data.AUTOTUNE,
        num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE,
        deterministic=False,
    )
)

for x in dataset:
  print(x)
```

```
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=420>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=50>)
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=380>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=40>)
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=390>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=45>)
```

For more details, check the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/CsvDataset?version=nightly).

**Update 1**:

```
print(tf.io.matching_files("/content/*csv"))
```

```
tf.Tensor(
[b'/content/test_1.csv' b'/content/test_10.csv' b'/content/test_11.csv'
 b'/content/test_12.csv' b'/content/test_13.csv' b'/content/test_16.csv'
 b'/content/test_17.csv' b'/content/test_18.csv' b'/content/test_19.csv'
 b'/content/test_2.csv' b'/content/test_20.csv' b'/content/test_24.csv'
 b'/content/test_3.csv' b'/content/test_4.csv' b'/content/test_5.csv'
 b'/content/test_6.csv' b'/content/test_7.csv' b'/content/test_9.csv'], shape=(18,), dtype=string)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242315/discussion-on-answer-by-alonetogether-tensorflow-integer-tensor-to-file-pattern).